# Converting btergm confidence interval to standard error (in odds-ratio terms)

Tags: r, confidence-interval, exponentiation, standard-error

I'm working on R's `btergm` and would like to convert the coefficients as well as their standard errors in odds-ratio terms for the ease of interpretation. However, the `btergm`'s output format differs from that of `ergm` in the sense that the former does not provide s.e. (instead, only confidence intervals are provided) and needs to subset relevant statistics using `@` instead of `$`. This is not a big deal for converting the coefficients to odds-ratio form because one only needs to apply `exp()` on the output's `coef`, but cannot use the same trick on confidence interval, it will not work.
I've referenced this [page](https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2016/04/25/convert-logistic-regression-standard-errors-to-odds-ratios-with-r/), but again, the recommended method only works for standard `glm` or `ergm` output format.

I put a btergm example output at below and hope someone could shed some light on this. Any help will be appreciated.

```css
btergm.fit <- readRDS(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/z43t55q0cr59vpb/btergm.fit.rds?dl=1"))

summary(btergm.fit)

                     Estimate    2.5%   97.5%
edges                  -5.0498497 -5.1876 -4.9032
gwesp.fixed.0           1.6242771  1.5634  1.6900
edgecov.LSP[[i]]        2.1065906  1.8466  2.3998
edgecov.warNet[[i]]     0.2866346  0.2010  0.3804
nodecov.polity         -0.0050764 -0.0132 -0.0001
nodecov.cinc            8.3308516  2.1716 12.3954
absdiff.polity         -0.1257948 -0.1443 -0.1160
absdiff.cinc           -4.8494093 -8.9411  0.4529
edgecov.contigMat[[i]]  3.2145679  3.1007  3.3061



#### generated using the following code ####

library(statnet)
library(btergm)
set.seed(10)

data("alliances", package = "xergm.common")

btergm.fit <- btergm(allyNet ~ edges + gwesp(0, fixed = TRUE) +
edgecov(LSP) + edgecov(warNet) + nodecov("polity") +
nodecov("cinc") + absdiff("polity") + absdiff("cinc") +
edgecov(contigMat), R = 50, parallel = "snow", ncpus = 2)
```

Comment: If you take the log of the CI range endpoints, the se will be 1.96 se’s from log coef. Just divide that difference by 1.96. (Generally R regression methods have an associated summary method and usually have a result that has a matrix of coefs and se’s. Check the help pages in the Value section of the summary function if such exists.  )

Comment: Package docs say: “ Temporal Exponential Random Graph Models (TERGM) estimated by maximum pseudolikeli- hood with bootstrapped confidence intervals, ” so technically they never calculated an s.e.  The method I described will be an attempt to use frequentist terminology and practice on Bayesian derived results

Comment: @IRTFM Got it, it seems that since CI = exp(log(or) +/- 1.96*se), so I can presumably calculate "se" = log(or)/z  (z wil be negative for or < 1). And since or = exp(coef)  so se = coef/z ?

Comment: First part is correct but se is not coef/z. You need to start with the range of the CI.

Comment: @IRTFM So do I use (upper - lower) in lieu of z?

Comment: Something like (upper-coef)/1.96. This is assuming that the CI’s and coef are still on the untransformed scale. In analyses that report odds ratios the coefficients are generally calculated on the log odds scale so it might be (log(upper)-log(OR))/1.96. Log(OR) should == coef.

Comment: @IRTFM Got it, many thanks. I'll take a look at my output.

Comment: But suppose one can get the s.e. this way, how to get the s.e. in odds-ratio terms? It doesn't look like I can directly apply `exp()` on the computed s.e.. I will also need to get `diag(vcov())` on some kind of s.e. matrix so that the odds-ratio se will be sqrt(odds-ratio^2 * diag(vcov(s.e)))), but since btergm doesn't actually have a s.e. matrix, I think it will be difficult.

Comment: I wasn’t expecting that you would be able to get an SE on the log odds scale. If you are able to get a vcov it’s likely to be on the log-odds scale but the docs suggested that this was being done with Bayesian methods. I don’t have that package and it sounds as though you need to consult a statistician who can explain the actions of this package. This is really the wrong forum for that task.

Comment: @IRTFM Understood, still, many thanks!

Comment: You can also use the [btergm.se](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xergm/versions/1.0/topics/btergm-class) function to compute standard errors. But note that there is no guarantee that the bootstrap distribution is symmetric and normal, as mentioned in the help file I referenced.